# assemble install error via npm

Tags: node.js, assemble

I wanted to install assemble.io but i get only this strange error messages.
I use node version 5.2.0, npm version 3.3.12, grunt 0.4.5. somebody has an idea what im doing wrong?

I install the plugin with this command:

```
npm install assemble --save-dev
```

This is the official docu for the installation
http://assemble.io/docs/Installation.html

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "assemble" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! node v5.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ENOSELF
npm ERR! Refusing to install assemble as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<my user>\Desktop\assemble test\npm-debug.log
```

this is the npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'assemble',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.12
3 info using node@v5.2.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData assemble
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData assemble
9 silly mapToRegistry name assemble
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/assemble
13 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/assemble
14 verbose request no auth needed
15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 11:07:31
16 verbose request id aa14641fec14dacb
17 verbose etag "8IAPJTPQFKJPLI2YBI4NXTZG4"
18 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/assemble
19 http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/assemble
20 verbose headers { date: 'Tue, 12 Jan 2016 10:07:31 GMT',
20 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
20 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
20 verbose headers   etag: '"8IAPJTPQFKJPLI2YBI4NXTZG4"',
20 verbose headers   age: '62',
20 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
20 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-ams4139-AMS',
20 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'HIT',
20 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '1',
20 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1452593251.405495,VS0,VE1',
20 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept' }
21 silly get cb [ 304,
21 silly get   { date: 'Tue, 12 Jan 2016 10:07:31 GMT',
21 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
21 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=300',
21 silly get     etag: '"8IAPJTPQFKJPLI2YBI4NXTZG4"',
21 silly get     age: '62',
21 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
21 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-ams4139-AMS',
21 silly get     'x-cache': 'HIT',
21 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '1',
21 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1452593251.405495,VS0,VE1',
21 silly get     vary: 'Accept' } ]
22 verbose etag https://registry.npmjs.org/assemble from cache
23 verbose get saving assemble to C:\Users\<my user>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\registry.npmjs.org\assemble\.cache.json
24 silly install normalizeTree
25 silly loadCurrentTree Finishing
26 silly loadIdealTree Starting
27 silly install loadIdealTree
28 silly cloneCurrentTree Starting
29 silly install cloneCurrentTreeToIdealTree
30 silly cloneCurrentTree Finishing
31 silly loadShrinkwrap Starting
32 silly install loadShrinkwrap
33 silly loadShrinkwrap Finishing
34 silly loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree Starting
35 silly install loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree
36 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
37 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
38 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
39 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
40 silly install printInstalled
41 verbose stack Error: Refusing to install assemble as a dependency of itself
41 verbose stack     at checkSelf (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\validate-args.js:40:14)
41 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
41 verbose stack     at LOOP (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
41 verbose stack     at chain (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:20:5)
41 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\validate-args.js:15:5
41 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:52:35
41 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
41 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:52:11
41 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
41 verbose stack     at asyncMap (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\async-map.js:51:8)
42 verbose cwd C:\Users\<my user>\Desktop\assemble test
43 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
44 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "assemble" "--save-dev"
45 error node v5.2.0
46 error npm  v3.3.12
47 error code ENOSELF
48 error Refusing to install assemble as a dependency of itself
49 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
49 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
50 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

gregor ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found the problem. The official documentation is out of date. i found the answer [there](https://github.com/assemble/assemble#release-history)

> Major refactor. Assemble was completely re-written from the ground-up as a standalone node.js library and is no longer a grunt plugin. Grunt plugin support has been moved to grunt-assemble. Please see that repo for additional details.

so you have to use

```
npm install grunt-assemble --save-dev
```

now, if you like to use assemble with grunt